# pointer to array of struct in loop with index

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

i have code, but it doesn't compile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    unsigned int ip;
    unsigned int mask;
} nic_t;

typedef struct {
    int nnic; /*number of nic*/
    nic_t *nic;
} host_t;

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    host_t *host = malloc(sizeof(host_t) * 5);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        host[i]->nnic = 3;
        host[i]->nic = malloc(sizeof(nic_t) * 3);
        for (j = 0; j < host[i]->nnic; j++) {
            host[i]->nic[j]->ip = 0x7f000001;
            host[i]->nic[j]->mask = 0xffffff00;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("ip = 0x%x, mask = 0x%x\n",
                    host[i]->nic[j]->ip,
                    host[i]->nic[j]->mask);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please explain to me how I need to address an array of structures in the program, that there was no compilation errors.
I have the following errors:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:18:10: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘host_t’)
test.c:19:10: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘host_t’)
test.c:21:11: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘host_t’)
test.c:22:11: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘host_t’)
test.c:28:13: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘host_t’)
test.c:29:13: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘host_t’)
```

thanks for all. it works.

Comment: `host[i]->nnic` : `host[i]` is not pointer. change to `host[i].nnic`

Comment: but it is pointer: host_t *host

Comment: No. `host` is a pointer to `host_t`, therefore `host[i]` is a `host_t`.

Comment: You have created 5 instances of host_t, and by accessing one of the instances by using host[i], you are not accessing a pointer, but one of the instances.  Similar to:  `int *a = malloc(sizeof(int)*10;`  Then you would use `a[1] = 3;`, not `&a[1] == 3;`  Because a[1] is an `int`, not a `int *`

Comment: when Type *pointer, pointer[i] meant *(pointer + i). type of pointer dereference is Type.

Comment: it is not obvious, but I'll know

Comment: Yes, It will become more obvious in time.  Pointers can be a challenge.

Comment: Someone noted `host[i]` is not a pointer, and you responded "but" `host` is a pointer ... it should be obvious that the latter doesn't contradict the former.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the `->` operator with the `.` operator.  If you have a struct `st`, then you can access its members by `st.member`.  If you have a struct pointer `st_ptr`, then `st_ptr->member` is short for `(*st_ptr).member`.  In your case, you are dereferencing the pointer with the array index.

Answer (score 1):

`host[i]` is not a pointer, it represents a single instance of `host_t`,

***therefore you must use the `.` operator***, not the `->` operator.

Change: (and all other occurrences)

```
From:  

host[i]->nnic = 3;  

To:  

host[i].nnic = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `.` and not `->`.

```
host[i]->nnic = 3;
```

should be

```
host[i].nnic = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of `host_t` structs, not `host_t *` pointers. So you want to say, e.g.:

```
host[i].nnic = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an array of *structures*. `host[i]` is a structure, not a pointer. So `.` instead of `->` is what you need.